# Odd Behavior with NPM and Dependencies

Tags: npm

It appears that NPM has an odd behavior where it depends on the package name (alphabetically) to determine what to install.

For example, if I have the following setup:

```
A depends on C@2.1.0
B depends on C@2.x
C@2.1.0 and C@2.2.0 are published
```

I will get the following installed

```
A
B
C@2.1.0
```

since `C@2.1.0` satisfies `2.x` as well.

Now, if I flip those around:

```
A depends on C@2.x
B depends on C@2.1.0
```

I get a really annoying behavior:

```
A
B
- C@2.1.0
C@2.2.0
```

`A` gets processed first because it's first alphabetically, it gets `C@2.2.0`, the latest that satisfies its condition. When it gets to `B`, `2.2.0` doesn't satisfy `2.1.0`, so `B` gets `C@2.1.0`, and I now have a duplicate.

It's essentially the same setup, but just the name of the dependent package affects how it's processed.

`npm dedupe` seems to have no effect in this scenario as well.

Is there a way to prevent this and to always get the results from the first scenario?